# How to add Windows context menu in any applications text entry right click?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, contextmenu

I need to add custom context menu in any text entry box of any application.
I made a custom keyboard.when I right-click on any text entry it should popup context menu with new context item named "run keyboard" .

Please help me.

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: C# my choice. or any CMD or Registry tweak

Comment: Or can I get cursor type from anywhere of my pc , not only from "windows form"?